# Problem with getting FCM token in firebase web code lab

Tags: javascript, firebase

Im going through The Odin Project currently and im learning about firebase. One of the tutorials im supposed to go through is this one: [firebase code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#10)

However I'm running into trouble in step 11. The Get your device token part of it. When I hit allow notifications instead of the token I get this error:

[image: Error]

Everything up to this point has worked fine. I don't think I messed any steps? I did everything again to make sure, but no luck. Im using brave browser if that helps. I also tried on Firefox but it didn't work. I also tried moving firebase-messaging-sw.js out of the public directory and into the web-start root but that also did not help. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you for looking!